# get average monthly value by divide from its monthly row count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have following datframe

```
created_time    shares_count
2021-07-01          250.0
2021-07-31          501.0
2021-08-02          48.0
2021-08-05          300.0
2021-08-07          200.0
2021-09-06          28.0
2021-09-08          100.0
2021-09-25          100.0
2021-09-30          200.0
```

did the grouping as monthly like this

```
df_groupby_monthly = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='created_time',freq='M')).sum()
df_groupby_monthly
```

[image]

Now how to get the average of these 'shares_count's by dividing from a sum of monthly rows?

ex: if the 07th month has 2 rows average should be 751.0/2 = 375.5, and the 08th month has 3 rows average should be 548.0/3 = 182.666, and the 09th month has 4 rows average should be 428.0/4 = 142.66

how to get like this final output

```
created_time   shares_count
2021-07-31       375.5
2021-08-31       182.666
2021-09-30       142.66
```

I have tried following

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='created_time',freq='M')).apply(lambda x: x['shares_count'].sum()/len(x))
```

this is working if only one column, multiple ones hard to get

Comment: please add a sample input to reproduce . `df.loc[:20].to_dict()`

Comment: This can be done, but we need the data *before* you grouped it, as text, not an image.

Comment: @srinath added more info

Comment: See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['created_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_time'])
output = df.groupby(df['created_time'].dt.to_period('M')).mean().round(2).reset_index()
output
###
  created_time  shares_count
0      2021-07        375.50
1      2021-08        182.67
2      2021-09        107.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```py
df=df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='created_time',freq='M')).agg({'shares_count':['sum', 'count']}).reset_index()
df['ss']=df[('shares_count','sum')]/df[('shares_count','count')]
```